# Faster sqlite 3 query in go? I need to process 1million+ rows as fast as possible

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, go

What's the fastest way to read a sqlite3 table in golang?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "/Users/robertking/go/src/bitbucket.org/thematicanalysis/optimization_test/robs.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from data")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

This takes 8 seconds in Go because `.Next` is [slow](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/379). In python a `fetchall` takes only 4 seconds! I'm rewriting in GO to gain performance not lose performance.

Here is the python code, I couldn't find an equivalent of `fetchall` in go:

```
import time

start = time.time()
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/robertking/go/src/bitbucket.org/thematicanalysis/optimization_test/robs.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
x = c.fetchall()
print time.time() - start
```

Edit: adding bounty. I'm reading the data in go, python and C, here are results. Dont want to use C, but will stick with python if GO isnt faster.:

```
py: 2.45s
go: 2.13s (using github.com/mxk/go-sqlite/sqlite3 instead of github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)
c:  0.32s
```

I feel like go should be closer to the c side of thing? anyone know how to make it faster? is it possible to avoid mutex with readonly mode?

edit:

It seems like all the sqlite3 implementations are slow (too much reflection and too many cgo calls for conversions). So i'll have to just write my own interface.

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  c0   REAL,
  c1   INTEGER,
  c15  TEXT,
  c16  TEXT,
  c17  TEXT,
  c18  TEXT,
  c19  TEXT,
  c47  TEXT,
  c74  REAL DEFAULT 0,
  c77  TEXT,
  c101 TEXT,
  c103 TEXT,
  c108 TEXT,
  c110 TEXT,
  c125 TEXT,
  c126 TEXT,
  c127 REAL DEFAULT 0,
  x    INTEGER
    PRIMARY KEY
);
```

and the query is dynamic but usually something like this:

```
SELECT c77,c77,c125,c126,c127,c74 from mytable
```

edit:

looks like i'll fork the sqlite3 implementation and make some methods that focus on performance,

this is an example of some code which is much faster:.

```
package main


/*
 #cgo LDFLAGS: -l sqlite3

#include "sqlite3.h"
*/
import "C"

import (
    //"database/sql"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type Row struct {
    v77 string
    v125 string
    v126 string
    v127 float64
    v74 float64
}

// cStr returns a pointer to the first byte in s.
func cStr(s string) *C.char {
    h := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    return (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(h.Data))
}

func main() {
    getDataFromSqlite()
}

func getDataFromSqlite() {
    var db *C.sqlite3
    name := "../data_dbs/all_columns.db"
    rc := C.sqlite3_open_v2(cStr(name+"\x00"), &db, C.SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, nil)

  var stmt *C.sqlite3_stmt;
  rc = C.sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, cStr("SELECT c77,c125,c126,c127,c74 from data\x00"), C.int(-1), &stmt, nil);
  rc = C.sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    var result C.double
    result = 0.0
    rc = C.sqlite3_step(stmt)
    for rc == C.SQLITE_ROW {
    C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(C.sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))))
    C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(C.sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))))
    C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(C.sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))))
    C.sqlite3_column_double(stmt, 3)
    result += C.sqlite3_column_double(stmt, 4)
        rc = C.sqlite3_step(stmt)
  }
    log.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: "This takes 8 seconds in Go because .Next uses reflection" --- where does this come from? Please share the profiling results.

Comment: Which takes more time, the Query call or the one million times checking for an error?

Comment: @itsLex the forloop has no checks / is empty.

Comment: @zerkms sorry, it could calls into CGO that are slow. Either way, I'm going to see if I can find other libraries.

Comment: here's a link: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/379

Comment: If you want 'fetch all' type functionality, try [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx). Although I doubt that will improve performance, since it uses the same standard library code under the covers.

Comment: [Suggested](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/379#issuecomment-354264670) to write a shim layer in C to implement that specific batching logic.

Comment: Instead of seeking performance gain in query read speed. Maybe you can process the row concurrently to see this overall performance is better then python or not.

Comment: Is it just me or is OP comparing apples with rocks? In the Python code, the result set is loaded (and I am not actually sure it is actually loaded or just a cursor prepared), whereas in the Go code, a noop loop is executed 1M+ times? According to my tests, this takes the vast majority of time (99.999%), since the cursor is actually iterated.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I added a loop in python and it was still around 4 seconds.

Comment: @robertking See my answer.

Comment: Do you still want to improve performance? Your latest results show Go is faster than Python. Also can you post the C code as well?

Comment: Since reflect is involved, it might help if you can give a data structure of the table.

Comment: One way forward would be to wrap a bit of C with Go's FFI.

Comment: yup, also i should already know the types in advance by looking at the query

Comment: @robertking according to my profiling, the most part is cgo call, not reflect (but I did not test with a large schema so I don't know for sure). profiling result: https://imgur.com/a/bVB6l

Answer (score 29):

## Introduction

My assumption was that we have a problem with how the performance is measured here, so I wrote a little Go program to generate records and save them into a SQLite database as well as a Python and Go implementation of a little task to do on those records.

You can find the according repository at https://github.com/mwmahlberg/sqlite3perf

## The data model

The records generated consist of

- `ID`: A [row ID generated by SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)
- `rand`: A [hex encoded](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/sqlite3perf/blob/6ed6f7776cfe2d7e9461db54fb12805fda604c36/cmd/generate.go#L120) [8 byte](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/sqlite3perf/blob/6ed6f7776cfe2d7e9461db54fb12805fda604c36/cmd/generate.go#L78) [pseudo-random value](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/sqlite3perf/blob/6ed6f7776cfe2d7e9461db54fb12805fda604c36/cmd/generate.go#L113)
- `hash`: A [hex encoded](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/sqlite3perf/blob/6ed6f7776cfe2d7e9461db54fb12805fda604c36/cmd/generate.go#L120) [SHA256 hash of the unencoded `rand`](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/sqlite3perf/blob/6ed6f7776cfe2d7e9461db54fb12805fda604c36/cmd/generate.go#L118)

The table's schema is relatively simple:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE bench (ID int PRIMARY KEY ASC, rand TEXT, hash TEXT);
```

First I generated 1.5M records and vacuumed the sqlite database afterwards with

```
$ ./sqlite3perf generate -r 1500000 -v
```

Next I called the Go implementation against those 1.5M records. Both the Go as well as the Python implementation basically do the same simple task:

1. Read all entries from the database.
2. For each row, decode the random value from hex, then create a SHA256 hex from the result.
3. Compare the generated SHA256 hex string against the one stored in the database
4. If they match, continue, otherwise break.

## Assumptions

My assumption explicitly was that Python did some type of lazy loading and/or possibly even execution of the SQL query.

## The results

### Go implementation

```
$ ./sqlite3perf bench
2017/12/31 15:21:48 bench called
2017/12/31 15:21:48 Time after query: 4.824009ms
2017/12/31 15:21:48 Beginning loop
2017/12/31 15:21:48 Acessing the first result set 
    ID 0,
    rand: 6a8a4ad02e5e872a,
    hash: 571f1053a7c2aaa56e5c076e69389deb4db46cc08f5518c66a4bc593e62b9aa4
took 548.32µs
2017/12/31 15:21:50 641,664 rows processed
2017/12/31 15:21:52 1,325,186 rows processed
2017/12/31 15:21:53 1,500,000 rows processed
2017/12/31 15:21:53 Finished loop after 4.519083493s
2017/12/31 15:21:53 Average 3.015µs per record, 4.523936078s overall
```

Note the values for "time after query" ( the time the query command took to return) and the time it took to access the first result set after the iteration over the result set was started.

### Python implementation

```
$ python bench.py 
12/31/2017 15:25:41 Starting up
12/31/2017 15:25:41 Time after query: 1874µs
12/31/2017 15:25:41 Beginning loop
12/31/2017 15:25:44 Accessing first result set
    ID: 0
    rand: 6a8a4ad02e5e872a
    hash: 571f1053a7c2aaa56e5c076e69389deb4db46cc08f5518c66a4bc593e62b9aa4
took 2.719312 s
12/31/2017 15:25:50 Finished loop after 9.147431s
12/31/2017 15:25:50 Average: 6.098µs per record, 0:00:09.149522 overall
```

Again, note the value for "time after query" and the time it took to access the first result set.

### Summary

It took the Go implementation quite a while to return after the SELECT query was send, while Python *seemed* to be blazing fast in comparison. However, from the time it took to actually access the first result set, we can see that the Go implementation is more than 500 times faster to actually access the first result set (5.372329ms vs 2719.312ms) and about double as fast for the task at hand as the Python implementation.

### Notes

- In order to prove the assumption that Python actually does lazy loading on the result set, each and every row and column had to be accessed in order to make sure that Python is forced to actually read the value from the database.
- I chose a hashing task because presumably the implementation of SHA256 is highly optimised in both languages.

## Conclusion

Python does seem to do lazy loading of result sets and possibly does not even execute a query unless the according result set is actually accessed. In this simulated scenario, mattn's SQLite driver for Go outperforms Python's by between roughly 100% and orders of magnitude, depending on what you want to do.

**Edit**: So in order to have a fast processing, implement your task in Go. While it takes longer to send the actual query, accessing the individual rows of the result set is by far faster. I'd suggest starting out with a small subset of your data, say 50k records. Then, to further improve your code, use [profiling](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) to identify your bottlenecks. Depending on what you want to do during processing, [pipelines](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) for example might help, but how to improve the processing speed of the task at hand is difficult to say without actual code or a thorough description.

Comment: It would be nice if the down voter would explain why the answer was down voted, so that I can improve it.

Comment: I guess your answer is very informative on WHY is slower and not HOW to make it faster which is the original question. Basically you are saying "Yeah, Python is 100% slower, deal with it". Still, I am upvoting.

Comment: @sfratini: Thanks you! My thought was that the answer is obvious. But thanks again for pointing out, I'll add it to the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg I appreciate your answer. The main objective is to try get within 2x or 3x C speed, rather than being comparable to python speed. I think i've found some ways to do this by modifying the go sqlite3 library code (was hoping I wouldnt have to do that, or that there would be a faster implementation out there).

Comment: @robertking As a garbage collected language, Go has some overhead when compared to C. What probably would work better is using Go's features to improve processing speed. I will try to expand my answer and the code with pipelines, which should make processing faster.

Comment: @robertking To say it more clear: every Go implementation I know is a wrapper for the C library, so you have C + some overhead. So using Go's concurrency feature imho is the only reasonable way to achieve speed improvements.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i agree. It's unfortunate that the wrappers are so slow. I managed to get it 4x faster by not using the wrappers.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty as I appreciate your effort. As @sfratini mentions, I was more looking for HOW not WHY. I was hoping one of these libraries had a fetchAll type method that I was missing.

Comment: @robertking I appreciate your decision and will try to add a sample solution both to the code and to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning Values from the retrieved rows [example read step 10](http://golang-basic.blogspot.com/2014/06/golang-database-step-by-step-guide-on.html).
Since `Query()` & `QueryRow()` returns a pointer to Rows and pointer to Row from the database query respectively, we can use the [Scan()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) functions on Rows and Row struct to get access to the values in the rows struct.

```
for rows.Next() {

 var empID sql.NullInt64
 var empName sql.NullString
 var empAge sql.NullInt64
 var empPersonId sql.NullInt64

 if err := rows.Scan(&empID, &empName, &empAge, 
                           &empPersonId); err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
 }

 fmt.Printf("ID %d with personID:%d & name %s is age %d\n",       
                   empID.Int64, empPersonId.Int64, empName.String, empAge.Int64)
}
```

We also used the Scan() function from Row struct. Scan() is the only method declared in the Row Struct.

```
func (r *Row) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
```